# Can't delete Google calendar appointments

Tags: calendars, gmail

My wife invited me to a couple weekly meetings on my Google calendar that are no longer valid.  They still appear in both the live tile and my glance screen, but not inside the calendar app.

I can also see them in the list if I ask Cortana "what am I doing today".  I've tried deleting them there, there aren't any errors, but they don't go away.  Help!

Comment: The reason they're showing up in the live tile, etc. but not the calendar itself is because when I delete these appointments it declines them rather than deletes them.  If I create a Google calendar appointment on my Windows phone and delete it on my Windows phone it deletes it correctly.  It seems to only decline them when they're created elsewhere.

Comment: I tried deleting andvre-adding the Google account to my Windows phone, but it didn't help.  I didn't do reboot.

Answer (score 1):

First, check if the appointment is still visible over the web in your browser?

There are 3 different options i would suggest:

1. deactivate the google-calender sync -> reboot phone -> check again -> (if you want activate the sync again)
2. delete the google-account -> reboot phone -> add the account again.
3. Delete the Calender-App from Windowsphone -> do a reboot -> re-install it.

The reboot is optional but i would recommend it because it clears the logs and clears also the cache.

I hope i could help :)